# Authorize.net Integration

Tags: csv, authorize.net

I have integrated authorize.net into my site. I heard there was a way for authorize.net to send a merchant weekly CSV files that document payment statuses of customers. The other option I've noticed is the Silent Post, which I prefer not to use. How do I get the weekly CSV files if it's even possible? I believe it doesn't work in the test.authorize.net, but it should work for their live site. I imagine I have to tweak my live account in some manner, but haven't found anything that allows me to perform this option or at least a guide to explain how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to contact Authorize.NET for them to setup the weekly reporting information back to you.  If i recall correctly it is emailed or something of that nature.  Just ring their customer support and they will get you going!